# "Trying to upload files larger than" error will not go away

Tags: uploads, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a woocommerce setup for virtual products. All products are around 10MB and uploaded fine. I do however keep getting the following error show up when browsing the store:

```
Trying to upload files larger than 128G is not allowed!
```

As you can see the file upload limit is 128GB and I have not tried uploading anything near the size of this. it was 128MB but i upped it to 128GB to try and get rid of the error.

Is there any reason why this could be happening?

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it turned out to be a bug with the Extra Product Options plugin. Was fixed by updating the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is PHP Memory Limit Error so you need to increase the Maximum Upload and PHP Memory Limit. Go in php.ini file and find and replace the code below.

```
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
post_max_size = 2000M
memory_limit = 3000M
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 180
```

You can set your custom value 'M'Megabytes.